# Java wrong value when reading from website

Tags: java, web

I'm trying to make a program, which gets a word from a website, which always gives you a random (German) word and counts how frequently a character is in the word. When I try my program with a stream from a list it works fine. If I read from the website, the word is displayed fine with System.out, but counting the letters does not work as intended. Here is my code:

```
public class WordCount {

  public static String charStat(String urlString) throws IOException {

/*    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("word");
    Stream<String> characterStream = list.stream();*/ //works totally fine every time

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    Stream<String> characterStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())).lines();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());//BufferedReader only used to print the word so I can control
                                      //if everything is working

    int[] charNumber = new int[26];//size is 26 cause the alphabet has 26 characters

    Runnable func = () -> {
      characterStream
          .map(String::toLowerCase)
          .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
          .filter(c -> c != ' ')
          .map(c -> c - (int) 'a')//subtracting 'a'(97 in ascii) so a is in position 0 of the array
          .forEach(i -> {charNumber[i]++;});
    };

    func.run();
    characterStream.close();
    return "a: " + charNumber[0];//returning how many times the letter a is present, could be any letter
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {//Ik that main shouldn't throw an exception
    System.out.println(charStat("https://randomeword.azurewebsites.net/api/word"));//the website im
                                                                                   //getting the word from
  }
}
```

Example from a fail:

word:

Klavierkonzert

the array:

[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

the should be:

[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

I don't know why this is happening as the word gets shown correctly with System.out.println();. So if I've done anything wrong let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two `URL.openStream()` calls is actually doing two calls to the website, thus recovering two different words.

Do only a single `URL.openStream()`call, and place the result in a variable. Use that variable for all your operations and you should achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Still an answer for some pitfalls:

- The German alphabet consist of more than 26 ASCII letters.
- German nouns start with an Uppercase letter (like Ü).
- The site sends the text in some encoding, this case in UTF-8.

So:

```
    String urlString = "https://randomeword.azurewebsites.net/api/word";
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    String contentType = conn.getContentType(); // "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    String charsetName = !contentType.contains("charset=") ? "UTF-8"
            : contentType.replaceFirst("^.*charset=([^;]*).*$", "$1");
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(charsetName); // Also checks validity.
    try (Stream<String> lineStream = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset)).lines()) {

        lineStream.findFirst().ifPresent(word -> {
            System.out.println("Word: " + word);
            Map<String, Integer> frequencies
                    = new TreeMap<>(Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
            word.codePoints()
                    .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                    .map(s -> s.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMANY))
                    .forEach(s -> frequencies.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum));
            System.out.println("Frequencies: " + frequencies);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The uppercase letter in the beginning is why I do .map(String::toLowerCase) so case dosen't matter. For the charset I now included it in the BufferedReader
Stream<String> characterStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()), "UTF-8").lines();

Comment: But how does it ÄÖÜ? You can add Locale parameter to toLowerCase.

Comment: The first url.openConnection() (line 3) is just to get the charset and the content type, or am I wrong?

Comment: Bug, I intended to use conn.openStream.